# Thermal radiations

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

everything having temperature above 0 k emits radiation. But those radiations depend upon temperature of the body and not on nature of the body. Why thermal radiations are not material dependent?

Answer (score 0):

That is not true, thermal radiation does depend on the nature of the matter radiating. For example, hot low-pressure nitrogen vapor shines pink/violet light, but hot low-pressure sodium vapor shines orange light.

If you were thinking of blackbody radiation, this is an idealized radiation generated in a special situation - when radiation is in thermodynamic equilibrium with matter. Only in such special ideal situation, the spectrum is the same irrespective of the kind of matter that is in equilibrium.

Comment: Thank you so much sir